# TKinter Gui with multiple files or frames in a Folder

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter program. This consists of a main file and a folder. In this folder there is a file that creates the TK window and a file that is supposed to create the frame in the TK window.
Can someone maybe help me get this program running. When you start the main file, the TK window is displayed, but the frame is not displayed in this window.

/main.py

```
from tkinter import *
from windows.main_window import *
from windows.main_window_frame1 import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    myWindow = MyFirstPanel(root)
    myWindow.start()
```

/windows/main_window.py

```
from tkinter import *
from main import *
from windows.main_window_frame1 import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MyFirstPanel():
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.root = root

        self.window_width = 1200
        self.window_height = 700
        self.window_size = (str(self.window_width) + 'x' + str(self.window_height))
        self.screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.screen_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
        self.window_pos_x = int((self.screen_width - self.window_width) / 2)
        self.window_pos_y = int((self.screen_height - self.window_height) / 2)

        self.root.title("Window1")
        self.root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.root.geometry(self.window_size + "+"
                           + str(self.window_pos_x) + "+"
                           + str(self.window_pos_y))

        Input_Frame1(self).pack()

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
```

/windows/main_window_frame1

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Input_Frame1(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(container, **kwargs)

        self.entry_city = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_city.pack()
```

Comment: You misspelled `__init__` in main_window_frame1.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Thats only here. In my code it was init. But I had found the misstake.

Comment: There still needs to be a root for the property.

Comment: Input_Frame1(self.root).pack()